# How to convert command line argument into string

Tags: python-2.7

I am practising questions for an exam that I will have in two weeks and whenever I try to attempt this question I become lost. I have tried putting args into int(args) but get "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:".

I am not allowed to use any for loops or any functions that would make this task simple.

```
import sys

args = sys.argv[1] 
total = 0

i = 0
while i  < len(args):
    total = total + args[i]

print total
```

Comment: how do you call this ?

Comment: In the command prompt by doing python (name of the python script) "apples" "oranges" the "" indicate they're arguments but whatever you declare in the quotes are strings regardless

Comment: From looking at the code its counting the amount of arguments when called upon and then adding that to the total if I am correct?

Comment: Your code gets the 1st argument. You call it `script.py one two three four` then argv[0] == "script.py", argv[1] == "one", argv[2] == "two" ... etc.  So this script sets args == "one" and then tries to add each single character of "one" to an integer - that does not work. State what it **should** do.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking me in regards to state what it should do as my previous comment is my understanding of what the code does...

Comment: This code "is given as is" and your task is to explain what it does?

Comment: Or "You got a task . that you fail to describe here. and wrote this code. and it crashes. And you do not know why or how to fix it. to solve the given taks. that is still unclear to me."

Comment: Apologies,  this code is given as is.

Comment: What this code currently does: Crahses if startet without any commandline params with `list index out of range` because you access `args = sys.argv[1]` when there is none, if you have commandlineparams it crashes because you try to add a char of the 1st commandline arg to a number with `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` on ` total = total + args[i]` - so congrats, someone gave you a code that crashes 2 different ways.

Comment: Simply paste your code int "www.pyfiddle.io" (in the big field). Put in nothing or some comma delimited arguments in the inputfield below  **Arguments (comma seperated)**  and hit run to see both crashes in the right column

Comment: I found that I have confused everyone that was looking at this piece of code... The purpose of this code was to add whatever was in the command line argument for example 1 2 would print out 3

Answer (score 1):

You could go with ["join"](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) option.

```
    import sys
' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
```

This will join your arguments with blank spaces between.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this:

```
import sys

print " ".join(sys.argv[1:]) # skip the programs name which is given as argv[0]
```

it will print all your arguments with one " " apart.

**Example:**

> `python` *`yourScriptName.py`* `one` `two` `three` `four`

will print

```
one two three four
```

---

To sum up your "numeric" command line params, you can use this:

```
import sys

def floatOrZero(tmp):
    f = 0.0
    try:
        f = float(tmp)   # make a float. # Lots of things are floats: 1.3e9
    except:
        f = 0.0          # this happens for non-floats

    return f


# sum all convertable parameters and print result
# using a list comprehension to convert args (strings) into
# floats or 0.0 if not convertable 
print "Sum of numeric entries: " , sum([floatOrZero(num) for num in sys.argv])
```